# Reverse sentence in C with only one whitespace character in between words

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, reverse

I am new to C and I am trying to reverse a string(char pointer) in C and store it in a char pointer. The condition is such that the reversed sentence shouldn't have any trailing or leading white spaces and also shouldn't have more than one white space between words.

Example:  Input: " the  sky  is  "

Expected Output: "si yks eht"

```
char * reverseWords(char * s){
    char* rev = malloc(24);

    int i=strlen(s)-1; int j = 0;
    for(; i>=0; i--){
    
        if(i == strlen(s)-1 && isalpha(s[i]) || i > 0 && (isalpha(s[i]) || s[i] == ' ' && isalpha(s[i-1]))){
            printf("i at pos: %d char: %c j:%d rev[j]: %c\n",i, s[i],j,rev[j]);
            rev[j++] = s[i];
            printf("j: %d rev[j]: %c\n",j,rev[j]);
        }
    }
    rev[j] = '\0';
   printf("After 1 rev:\"%s\"\n",rev);  
return rev;
}
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. I know my if condition logic is not right, could you please help me correct it?
2. Also when I try to print rev[j] I am getting

```
i at pos: 13 char:   j:0 rev[j]: �
j: 1 rev[j]: �
i at pos: 12 char: s j:1 rev[j]: �
j: 2 rev[j]: �
i at pos: 11 char: i j:2 rev[j]: �
j: 3 rev[j]: �
....
```

I was expecting a seg fault but I see unrecognized characters while accessing rev[j] before and after initializing

3. I have seen some codes where they access malloced char arrays this way --> *rev++ = *s++. What is the right way to do it? When should I access using indices (rev[0]) vs pointers *rev = *s ?

Edit: Worked on my logic and this seems to be working now:

```
char * reverseWords(char * s){
    
    char* rev = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char))*(1024);
    
    int i=0, j = 0, p =0;
    
    for(int i = strlen(s)-1; i>=0; ){
        while(i >=0 && s[i] == ' ')
            i--;
        
        j= i-1;
        
        while(j >= 0 && s[j] != ' ')
            j--;
        
        if(i >= 0 && j >=-1 ){
        for(int k=i; k > j; k--){
            rev[p] = s[k];
            
            p++;
        }
        rev[p++] = ' ';
        }
        
        i = j-1;
        
    }
   
    rev[p-1]='\0';

return rev;
}
```

Comment: Why not simplify the logic and do two passes? Strip out leading and multiple consecutive white space first, then reverse the whole array.

Comment: Also: You know exactly how long the reversed string must be, son don't guess the number of bytes you allocate.

Comment: The unknown characters come from printing uninitialized characters: After you assign to `rev[j++]`, `rev[j]` is the character after the one you've just assigned.

Comment: You could start the function by stepping over any leading spaces: Something like `while(*s == ' ') ++s;` should help.

Comment: @MOehm Thank you, I implemented a logic based on your suggestion. Do you mean to use something like `char* rev = (char *)malloc(sizeof(s));` ?

Comment: Could someone pls summarize how to access char arrays and char pointers?

Comment: No. `sizeof(s)` will be the size if the pointer. Use `malloc(strlen(s) + 1)`, which gives you enough memory to store the original string (in case you don't have to remove any spaces) plus the null terminator.

Comment: No need to call `strlen` inside loops. `s` doesn't change therefore `strlen(s)` doesn't change.